# When an existing user tries to log in using Phone authentication, the sms timeout error occurs

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I've been trying to use Phone authentication for my android app using Firebase. It's successful in adding a new user.But whenever, an existing user logs in, an sms timeout occurs.

Here's my otp verification function

```
  void verifyOtp({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String verificationId,
    required String userOtp,
    required Function onSuccess,
  }) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential creds =
          PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: userOtp);
      User? user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(creds)).user!;

      if (user != null) {
        _uid = user.uid;
    bool isExistingUser = await checkExistingUser();

        if (isExistingUser) {
          DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _firestore.collection("users").doc(_uid).get();
          _userModel = UserModel.fromMap(snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
        } else {
          _userModel = UserModel();
        }

        onSuccess();
      }

      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Here's my debug console.

```
D/FirebaseAuth(25423): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( QNt4bjTAFlXEwEMpdLAg4GsjgoF2 ).
2
I/flutter (25423): User Exists
W/FirebaseAuth(25423): [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.
```

I'm not able to understand the exact error for which this problem is occuring.